# Why is Modulo in MySQL (with negative number) giving unexpected results?

Tags: mysql, math, modulo

While I'll admit I'm a bit sketchy on modulo operations of negative numbers, I do know that

```
-2 mod 50 = 48
```

in just about every online modulo calculator as well as LibreOffice Calc:

```
=MOD(-2,50)
```

And Python:

```
-2 % 50
```

This number (`48`) conveniently is the answer I need for a function I am writing in a MySQL procedure. However, in MySQL:

```
SELECT MOD(-2,50)
```

Gives me `-2` as a result.

What is the reason for this, and how do I get the result I am looking for in MySQL?

---

For Posterity:

As of 2018 the following languages provide these different results from `-2 % 50`:

**48**

- Python
- R
- Google Calculator
- Google Sheets
- LibreOffice Calc
- Ubuntu Calculator

**-2**

- Javascript
- MySQL
- Microsoft Calculator
- PHP

And as pointed out in the comments, a more exhaustive list is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733829/mysql-mod-is-broken-is-this-the-best-alternative).

Comment: The Windows calculator computes `-2 % 50 = -2`.  So, I can't reproduce something which disagrees with MySQL.

Comment: Google Calculator also equals 48: https://www.google.com/search?q=-2+%25+50

Comment: PHP says -2 as well https://3v4l.org/8scNn

Comment: And... R gives 48. The war is over. Long live the king.

Comment: Wiki page contains table with modulo operation behavior for signed numbers for different languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: You can add C, C++ to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement your own version of `MOD` using division as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733829/mysql-mod-is-broken-is-this-the-best-alternative) but probably the simplest solution is to perform `MOD` twice, adding 50 between operations:

```
SELECT MOD(MOD(input, 50)+50, 50)
```

This will give you correct results regardless of the input value.

Answer (score 2):

In sql when you do modulo example Mod(x,y) and x is a negative answer the result is given from 0 to x-1 range. hence you are getting the wrong output.

Perhaps you can model the question in such a way that you are performing the same form of mod.

Try doing the querying like this.

```
select ((x+y)+y%y) -> select ((-2+50)+50%50)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, many MOD functions and % operators in the world of programming languages do not implement a modulo function in the mathematical sense: for negative arguments, they return -(|a| mod b) instead.

Workarounds:

- if a < 0, use MOD(a + b - 1, b);
- use MOD(a + c, b) where c is a multiple of b if it is guaranteed that a + c >= 0 and there is no overflow.